# How can I set the offset dynamically/by argument using tooltipsy?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using tooltipsy to show tooltips on my site. It works great so far but I just want to be able to indicate the offset from the link in a similar way I get the url.

in my javascript i have this for the binding:

```
$('.tooltip-ajax', ui_context).tooltipsy({        

    offset: [0,5],

    className: 'tooltipsy-content',

    content: function ($el, $tip) { 

    var url = $el.data('url');            
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $tip.html(data);
    });
    return 'loading...';
    }
});
```

so I can do this inside a link:

class="tooltip-ajax" data-url="my_ajax_content_url"

this works great, but i'd also like to be able to set the offset maybe with a data-offsetx and data-offsety attributes

So far I tried to get started by replacing

offset: [0,5]

by

offset: function () { 
return [-20,-30]; }

but it doesn't like it.

Any ideas why this doesn't work or how to do this in a better way?

thank you very much in advance

Comment: `offset` option is not a function. It's an array.

Comment: I don't believe `offset` ever gets called as a function, so the function assigned to it is never executed, thus it has no value. Maybe try making it a self-executing function instead?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will give self-executing functions a try. In the meantime I just opted by defining several bindings with different offsets.